# TCP server device for USB access readers

Tags: usb, tcp, sockets, serial, rs232

I have a BarCode reader that spits out data over a Virtual COM port (RS232 Serial) through a USB cable. I have a server running and managing a facility, and I need to read data coming off the BarCode reader over TCP/IP. The catch is that my software on the server can't read USB devices/Serial devices. It can do sockets, and I am trying to find a device with a TCP Client that accepts a USB connection and sends data over TCP Socket to a Server. Any suggestions?